# Angular HttpClient analogue for fetch keepalive flag

Tags: angular, fetch, angular-httpclient

I am developing an Angular application using its `HttpClient`. I found that `fetch()` Api does support the useful `keepalive` option to maintain the connection beyond the livetime of the html page.

```js
fetch(someUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data,
  keepalive: true,
});
```

I cant seem to find anything similar when using HttpClient. Does this option exist at all?

Comment: What would be your usecase for using `keepalive` ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler: Make an API call to the server when the user closes the browser tab to do some cleanup stuff. I do this in the beforeunload handler. Without the flag the call is not made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `HttpModule` does not rely on the `fetch` API but the XHR.

So no, there is no such option.

Since 16.1, you can use `withFetch()` to switch to the `fetch` API base implementation but it doesn't support the `keepAlive` option either.

You could open a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=2-feature-request.yaml) though.